# new learner of c, the project is not compiled?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

After i Compiled the programme,  i click run. it still tips me " project is not compiled" why? i am sorry, i am a new learner of c.

i am using `dev c++`, on xp,  `ctrl+F9` compile then `ctrl+F10` run
it shows  `project is not compiled`

[image]

Comment: are you using an IDE or compiling from the command line?

Comment: It compiles just [fine](http://ideone.com/ZLP8X), Something to do with your project settings.And actually, You also used the correct return type for `main()` which is a rarity these days with new learners :) So +1 for that.

Comment: Which operating system and compiler are you using?

Comment: Please describe the system you're using. Which OS and how are you coding - text editor, EMACS, Visual Studio etc...

Comment: After you *click* on compile, what is the output? I would imagine that you have an error.

Comment: You are probably trying to compile whole project, and since you have main function defined in other c files, you are getting a linker error.

Comment: @run - What is the contents of the other file i.e. `1c.c`

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
     int main(void)
     {
         printf("hello,C! \n");
         system("pause");
         return 0;
         }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
multiple definition of main
```

Maybe in your project there is 2 Main function..
You should at least delete/change one..

if I see, there is 1-3.c and 1c.c

and the compile is error..

```
[Build Error]
```

CMIIW

Comment: but when i close the 1c.c. the problem is still there, how to correct it. thank you

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of having the file open or closed - I think it's that the file exists at all and has a main function.  Try commenting out the main function in that file and compiling.

Comment: Don't just close it, remove it from your project. Make separate projects per executable. And for what it's worth, don't use Dev-C++ (especially the version you're using) but one of the [the excellent alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dev-c%2b%2b/info)

Answer (score 2):

Delete the file `1c.c`. You cannot have two `int main` functions.

Comment: thank you, you are right, but i want to practice more c programme under c project. why in this project i can only create one c file.

Comment: @run - You can. You need to understand that an executable needs to have one starting point. But your project is trying to have two! So the compiler spits it out. Please read up about `static`, header files, `extern`.

Comment: You can have many files per project. But each project can only have one main().